# Are Brahmacharis(male) allowed to grow hair(and facial hair)?

Tags: brahmacharya

We often see vedic society people who are practising studenthood, to have almost clean shaved heads but nowadays people with short hair are seen preaching and learning the vedas, is it recommended to have hair(and facial hair)?
They say kama resides in the hair, so is it advisable for people pursuing student -hood to grow long hair(with facial hair)?

Answer (score 5):

According to Manu Smriti and other scriptures, the student may shave his entire head or he may keep a Jata. He may even shave the whole head except the hair of the top-knot (Shikha) portion.

**Therefore, since keeping a Jata is an option, growing hair is allowed, but it should be like a proper Jata and not like a modern day shortish haircut.**

[Verse 2.219](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199695.html)

> मुण्डो वा जटिलो वा स्यादथ वा स्यात्शिखाजटः ।
>  नैनं
>   ग्रामेऽभिनिम्लोचेत् सूर्यो नाभ्युदियात् क्व चित् ॥ २१९ ॥
>
> muṇḍo vā jaṭilo vā syādatha vā syātśikhājaṭaḥ |
>  nainaṃ
>   grāme'bhinimlocet sūryo nābhyudiyāt kva cit || 219 ||
>
> He may have his head shaved, or wear his hair in braids, or have only
>   the top-hair braided. The sun should never set, nor should it rise,
>   while he is still in the village.—(219)

Alternate translation:

> 2.219. A (student) may either shave his head, or wear his hair in braids, or braid one lock on the crown of his head; the sun must never
>   set or rise while he (lies asleep) in the village.

Other scriptures also state what Manu has to say in this regard:

> Gautama (1.29).—‘With head shaven, with hair in braids or with
>   top-hair braided.’
>
> Āpastamba Dharmasūtra (1.2.31,32).—‘With braided locks;—or others may
>   have the head shaven, leaving the top-hair braided.’
>
> Vaśiṣṭha (7-8).—‘Dependent on the Teacher, with hair braided or with
>   top-hair braided, he shall walk behind the Teacher when he walks.’
>
> Viṣṇu (28.41).—‘The Religious Student shall have either his hair all
>   shaven or all in braids.’

All these above quotes are taken from the linked page. And, I could not find anything on the facial hair.

Comment: Thank you, Rickross for sharing what ever you know,

Comment: No problem :) and welcome to the site @user62720